# Are these translations of 'metaphor', 'love', 'death', 'dream' correct?

Tags: translation, meaning

metaphor 隠喩 (in'yu)
love 愛 (Ai)
death 死 (Shi)
dream  夢 (yume) 
I ma looking for the words (translations) which are..hmm how to say it.. which are the "most general" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**metaphor**
<sub>My understanding on this section is limited, but here is what my research uncovered. Feel free to comment if this is incorrect.</sub>
・`暗喩【あんゆ】` is specifically `metaphor`. However, `メタファー` is more commonly used these days.
・`直喩【ちょくゆ】` is specifically `simile`. Similes use `like` or `as` which in Japanese equates to `～のような`  or `～みたい`, irrespectively.
・`四字熟語【よじじゅくご】` is a four-character idiom that represents a classic tale or proverb (often Chinese in origin). This is comparable to `That's the last straw!` in English. Without knowing the proverb `It is the last straw that breaks the camel’s back.` this interjection wouldn't make any sense. Japanese has a lot of *yojijukugo*.
・`比喩{ひゆ}` is used for the general category of metaphors, similes, idioms, and *yojijukugo*.

**love**
・`愛｛あい｝` is far and away the most common word for love. Keep in mind that it is a noun, not a verb. To say, `～ loves ～` you would have to use `～は～を愛してる`, which is literally `～ is in the state of loving ～`. I once read that this word originally came from the Buddhist concept of attachment (thus originally having a negative connotation), but I can't find the evidence for that at the moment.

**death**
・`死【し】` is correct as a noun. The verb is `死ぬ`. Keep in mind that this is a more extreme concept in Japanese culture than in the US. For example, the worst profanities I ever heard in Japan include this idea. Otherwise the concept of `profanity` seemed foreign to people and its equivalence was conveyed grammatically (rather than semantically). All that to say, use it wisely.

**dream**
・`夢{ゆめ}` is `dream` in the literal sense of what happens when you sleep. `To have a dream` is literally `to see a dream`, `夢を見る`.

So, why those four words specifically?

Comment: thank you. The four words I am going to use in my poetry :)

Comment: I see. Sorry they put this on hold. It looks to me like "prior research effort is clearly indicated." But, at least you were able to get your answer before the topic was closed.  ✌